# Sort order / inequality filters on AppEngine ShortBlob fields

Tags: google-app-engine, blob, unsigned, signed

If I have an AppEngine datastore field that contains a ShortBlob entry (i.e. a byte[] of length 500 or less), and I do a query on this field with an inequality filter or a sort-order, are the bytes interpreted as signed values for the required comparisons?

For example, is `[0xC0, 0x00]` considered larger (interpreted as unsigned) or smaller (interpreted as signed, i.e. `[-0x40, 0x00]`) than `[0x00, 0x00]`?

How about the byte order? Is it LSB or MSB? I.e. is `[0x10, 0x00]` considered larger or smaller than `[0x00, 0x10]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs

> BlobProperty - Uninterpreted byte string: if you set indexed=True, up to
>   500 characters, indexed;

All you will get is string comparison.

Comment: That should mean it's an unsigned comparison with the first byte carrying the most weight, correct?

Comment: Try it ;-)  You will soon find out.

Comment: Will do... it's just always a bit of a pain with AppEngine, because you can't always rely on the dev-server handling things exactly like the production server... :)

Comment: I have never found basic things like indexes, orders, querying to differ.  Speed of consistency, performance, memcache eviction are obviously different.

Comment: One basic thing that differs, for example, is support for chunked transfer encoding for blob uploads (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127500/does-appengine-blobstore-support-chunked-transfer-encoding-for-uploads-status-4). Unfortunately, for me this means that I'm not going to feel comfortable simply trusting that the two behave the same, unless I can find a comprehensive list of differences, which I'm sure no-one has compiled... But in general I would agree that this particular issue here is such a basic feature that it *has* to behave the same... :)